# C# .NET 7 Blazor WASM App and Server, can't change listening port 5000

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-7.0

I have created my first Blazor application.
The application has an API(Server), Client and a Shared Class Library.

When I publish the app to a local folder and then copy it to IIS it is working but the listening port for the API stays on http://localhost:5000. I am running the app on https://example.com so it won't be able to access http://localhost:5000 because of the mix in http and https.

Where can I change that port so that it can work on https://example.com?

Comment: When creating the Website on IIS, does the Client and Server have different ports you need to bind? Client:80, Server:5000?

Comment: Yes it does have